# How to disable user selections in Quiver charts?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I would like to know how to disable user selections in Quiver charts. I would like to prevent a user clicking for example on bar charts, i.e. disabling the functionality shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the interactions and filter down of charts within quiver.